# Make import paths explicit on build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm setting up `webpack.resolve.modules` on webpack's config to resolve the import paths, however on my resulting build files I'm still getting the absolute path.

For example:

`import { Input, Button, Message } from 'src/index';`

instead of:

`import { Input, Button, Message } from '../../src/index';`

How can I make webpack produce explicit relative paths on the resulting dist files?

Comment: That does not look right. Did you miss a `./` there? `./src/index`?

Comment: Nope, I'm using src/index since I setup that folder on resolve.modules. I'll update my question to clarify that